# How do I dynamically change class in Angular direcitves?

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to write a custom directive to replace similar buttons on my page. But when I move ng-class into directive's template, it's not working anymore. Is it wrong to include ng-class within custom directive? Should I use addClass and removeClass in link function instead?

html:

```
  <dt-button ngclass="{'active-button': selectedRows.length >=1}" text="tablebuttons.delete" icon="v-delete" ng-click="deleteDialog()"></dt-button>
```

directive

```
.directive('dtButton', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: {
        icon: '@',
        text: '@',
        ngclass: '='
      },
      link: function(scope, ielem, iattrs) {

      },

      template: 
      '<button ng-class="{{ngclass}}">' +
      '<span class="{{icon}}"></span>' +
      '<p translate="{{text}}">' +
      '</p>' + 
      '</button>'
    }
  })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try use this. change `class` to `ng-class` in your template.
you pass a model to directive for `text` in view while it is not 2 way data binding.

```
template: 
  '<button class="active-button" ng-class="{{ngclass}}">' +
  '<span class="{{icon}}"></span>' +
  '<p translate="{{text}}">' +
  '</p>' + 
  '</button>'
```

```js
// Code goes here
var app = angular
  .module('MyApp', [])
  .controller('Main', ['$scope',
    function($scope) {
      var vm = this;
      vm.selectedRows = 4;
      vm.deleteDialog = function() {
        console.log(vm.selectedRows);
        vm.selectedRows = 0;

      }

    }
  ])
  .directive('dtButton', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: {
        icon: '@',
        text: '@',
        ngclass: '='
      },
      controller: "Main as ctrl",
      link: function(scope, ielem, iattrs) {

      },

      template: '<button  ng-class="ngclass" >' +
        '<p>{{text}}</p>' +
        '</button>'
    }
  });
```

```css
.active-button {
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div class="main-content" ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="Main as ctrl">
  <div>
    <dt-button ngclass="{'active-button':ctrl.selectedRows >=1}" ng-click="ctrl.deleteDialog()" text="delete"></dt-button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the snippet, it doesn't change class when model changes

Comment: do some other things in the controller to change the value of $scope.selectedRows

Comment: For different buttons there are different conditions firing ng-class, so I'm trying to pass the expression of ng-class from outside, I'm not sure if this is the right method.

Comment: different conditions firing with `selectedRows` or other things?

Comment: `selectedRows` and some other variables from the same controller

Answer (score 0):

I think nothing wrong with your approach to put ng-class at template of directive. I have tried to reproduce your code snippet at this **[plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/2Jh2W5NQQVvO0Rf5ybyB?p=preview)** it is give the correct class name `active-button` which i defined at `style.css` with background color blue. But because i don't know much about expression `selectedRows.length >=1` on your `ngclass` attribute, i make it just to `true` value which will always give `active-button` class to the element. When you change it to false, it will remove the `active-button` class.

My guess is seem something wrong with your expression `selectedRows.length >=1`. At following element declaration :

```
<dt-button ngclass="{'active-button': selectedRows.length >=1}" text="tablebuttons.delete" icon="v-delete" ng-click="deleteDialog()"></dt-button>
```

Maybe you can check by bind those expression return value to the element with double curly brace or any other way.

Small correction for your code, you may need to put semicolon ( `;` ) at the end of `return` keyword inside `.directive()`.

Comment: Yes It gives the class to the element in the beginning, but the class will not be changed again if you change the value, see this https://plnkr.co/edit/6cue4ZG8dM1WHW17oAZn?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```js
jimApp = angular.module("mainApp",  []);

jimApp.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope){
  $scope.selectedRows = [0];
  $scope.tablebuttons = {delete:"Delete"};
  $scope.deleteDialog = function(){
    $scope.selectedRows = [];
    }
});

jimApp.directive('dtButton', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: {
        icon: '@',
        text: '@',
        myClass: '@'
      },
      link: function(scope, ielem, iattrs) {
        console.log(scope.myClass);
      },

      template: 
      '<button class="{{myClass}}">' +
      '<span class="{{icon}}"></span>' +
      '{{text}}' +
      '</button>'
    }
  })
```

```css
.active-button{
  background:red;
  }
.inactive-button{
  background:#ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="mainApp" ng-controller="mainCtrl">
  <dt-button my-class="{{selectedRows.length?'active-button':'inactive-button'}}" text="{{tablebuttons.delete}}" icon="v-delete" ng-click="deleteDialog()"></dt-button>
</div>
```